# Excel VBA adding conditional formatting for expired date

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns, ColumnA contains a date (ex. `3/15/2014`) and ColumnB has a formula of `ColumnA+30` (ex. `=$A1+30`).

What I need to do is add a conditional formatting through VBA wherein `ColumnB` cells turns red if it's value (which is a date) is less than the date today.

Basically `ColumnA` is for "Manufactured Date" and `ColumnB` is "Expiration Date" which should be 30 days after manufacturing. The goal is to turn red cells in `ColumnB` if they are already expired. The Conditional Formatting must be added through VBA code.

I tried recording a macro but the results were bad.

```
Sheet2.Range("K2:L" & Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLessEqual, _
    Formula1:="=""Today()"""
Sheet2.Range("K2:L" & Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).FormatConditions(Sheet2.Range("K2:L" & Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Sheet2.Range("K2:L" & Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Sheet2.Range("K2:L" & Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Comment: show us please your current code

Comment: My code might be hard to understand but there you go, I have attached it. It is not exactly ColumnA and ColumnB but a more complicated example instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
    'change Sheet2 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B").FormatConditions
        .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(B1<>"""",B1<TODAY())"
        With .Item(.Count)
            .Interior.Color = 255
            .SetFirstPriority
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```